# ¿Cómo establezco el Idioma en Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

No consigo hacer funcionar el idioma en este script de [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Estoy dejándome algo? Alguien puede echarme un cable? Gracias.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker-es.js">

<script>
  jQuery( function() {  
    jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults(jQuery.datepicker.regional['es']);
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "{$ruta}/img/iconmonstr-calendar-4.svg",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date",
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Este funciona (también en [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/mk8gppht/5/)):

**Nota:** Verifica que tienes las librerías necesarias.

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN: aplicar código CSS**

En base un comentario, he colocado un fragmento de código CSS y aprovecho para señalar que jQuery ofrece a través de su [download builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/) un sin número de archivos CSS si queremos personalizar nuestros componentes.

**Haciendo clic en los extremos del calendario se podrá cambiar de fecha**.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '&#x3c;Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
            'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'
        ],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'
        ],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Mi&eacute;rcoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'S&aacute;bado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mi&eacute;', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'S&aacute;b'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'S&aacute;'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        appendText: 
          ' <br/>Haga click para introducir una fecha<br>'+
          'Para cambiar de mes, clic en los extremos superiores del calendario'
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-helper-hidden {
display: none;
}
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
border: 0;
clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
height: 1px;
margin: -1px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 1px;
}
.ui-helper-reset {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
line-height: 1.3;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 100%;
list-style: none;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix:before,
.ui-helper-clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix:after {
clear: both;
}
.ui-helper-zfix {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
filter:Alpha(Opacity=0); /* support: IE8 */
}

.ui-front {
z-index: 100;
}


/* Interaction Cues
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-disabled {
cursor: default !important;
pointer-events: none;
}


/* Icons
----------------------------------*/
.ui-icon {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-top: -.25em;
position: relative;
text-indent: -99999px;
overflow: hidden;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.ui-widget-icon-block {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -8px;
display: block;
}

/* Misc visuals
----------------------------------*/

/* Overlays */
.ui-widget-overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.ui-datepicker {
width: 17em;
padding: .2em .2em 0;
display: none;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header {
position: relative;
padding: .2em 0;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
width: 1.8em;
height: 1.8em;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover {
top: 1px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev {
left: 2px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
right: 2px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover {
left: 1px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover {
right: 1px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -8px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -8px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title {
margin: 0 2.3em;
line-height: 1.8em;
text-align: center;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select {
font-size: 1em;
margin: 1px 0;
}
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month,
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year {
width: 45%;
}
.ui-datepicker table {
width: 100%;
font-size: .9em;
border-collapse: collapse;
margin: 0 0 .4em;
}
.ui-datepicker th {
padding: .7em .3em;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
border: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker td {
border: 0;
padding: 1px;
}
.ui-datepicker td span,
.ui-datepicker td a {
display: block;
padding: .2em;
text-align: right;
text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane {
background-image: none;
margin: .7em 0 0 0;
padding: 0 .2em;
border-left: 0;
border-right: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button {
float: right;
margin: .5em .2em .4em;
cursor: pointer;
padding: .2em .6em .3em .6em;
width: auto;
overflow: visible;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current {
float: left;
}

/* with multiple calendars */
.ui-datepicker.ui-datepicker-multi {
width: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group {
float: left;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group table {
width: 95%;
margin: 0 auto .4em;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi-2 .ui-datepicker-group {
width: 50%;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi-3 .ui-datepicker-group {
width: 33.3%;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi-4 .ui-datepicker-group {
width: 25%;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group-last .ui-datepicker-header,
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-group-middle .ui-datepicker-header {
border-left-width: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker-multi .ui-datepicker-buttonpane {
clear: left;
}
.ui-datepicker-row-break {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
font-size: 0;
}

/* RTL support */
.ui-datepicker-rtl {
direction: rtl;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev {
right: 2px;
left: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next {
left: 2px;
right: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-prev:hover {
right: 1px;
left: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-next:hover {
left: 1px;
right: auto;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane {
clear: right;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button {
float: left;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current,
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group {
float: right;
}
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group-last .ui-datepicker-header,
.ui-datepicker-rtl .ui-datepicker-group-middle .ui-datepicker-header {
border-right-width: 0;
border-left-width: 1px;
}

/* Icons */
.ui-datepicker .ui-icon {
display: block;
text-indent: -99999px;
overflow: hidden;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
left: .5em;
top: .3em;
}

/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget {
font-family: segoe ui,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 1.1em;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget input,
.ui-widget select,
.ui-widget textarea,
.ui-widget button {
font-family: segoe ui,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
border: 1px solid #327E04;
}
.ui-widget-content {
border: 1px solid #dfd9c3;
background: #f5f3e5 url("images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_f5f3e5_1x100.png") 50% top repeat-x;
color: #312e25;
}
.ui-widget-content a {
color: #312e25;
}
.ui-widget-header {
border: 1px solid #d4ccb0;
background: #ece8da url("images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_100_ece8da_500x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
color: #433f38;
font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-widget-header a {
color: #433f38;
}

/* Interaction states
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
.ui-button,

/* We use html here because we need a greater specificity to make sure disabled
works properly when clicked or hovered */
html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:hover,
html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:active {
border: 1px solid #327E04;
background: #459e00 url("images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_15_459e00_1x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
font-weight: bold;
color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-default a,
.ui-state-default a:link,
.ui-state-default a:visited,
a.ui-button,
a:link.ui-button,
a:visited.ui-button,
.ui-button {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus,
.ui-button:hover,
.ui-button:focus {
border: 1px solid #327E04;
background: #67b021 url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_25_67b021_1x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
font-weight: bold;
color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-hover a,
.ui-state-hover a:hover,
.ui-state-hover a:link,
.ui-state-hover a:visited,
.ui-state-focus a,
.ui-state-focus a:hover,
.ui-state-focus a:link,
.ui-state-focus a:visited,
a.ui-button:hover,
a.ui-button:focus {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-visual-focus {
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgb(94, 158, 214);
}
.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active,
a.ui-button:active,
.ui-button:active,
.ui-button.ui-state-active:hover {
border: 1px solid #d4ccb0;
background: #fafaf4 url("images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_100_fafaf4_1x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
font-weight: bold;
color: #459e00;
}
.ui-icon-background,
.ui-state-active .ui-icon-background {
border: #d4ccb0;
background-color: #459e00;
}
.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
color: #459e00;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Interaction Cues
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
border: 1px solid #e8e1b5;
background: #fcf0ba url("images/ui-bg_glass_55_fcf0ba_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
color: #363636;
}
.ui-state-checked {
border: 1px solid #e8e1b5;
background: #fcf0ba;
}
.ui-state-highlight a,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight a,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight a {
color: #363636;
}
.ui-state-error,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-error,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {
border: 1px solid #e3a345;
background: #ffedad url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_95_ffedad_1x100.png") 50% top repeat-x;
color: #cd5c0a;
}
.ui-state-error a,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-error a,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-error a {
color: #cd5c0a;
}
.ui-state-error-text,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-error-text,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-error-text {
color: #cd5c0a;
}
.ui-priority-primary,
.ui-widget-content .ui-priority-primary,
.ui-widget-header .ui-priority-primary {
font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-priority-secondary,
.ui-widget-content .ui-priority-secondary,
.ui-widget-header .ui-priority-secondary {
opacity: .7;
filter:Alpha(Opacity=70); /* support: IE8 */
font-weight: normal;
}
.ui-state-disabled,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-disabled {
opacity: .35;
filter:Alpha(Opacity=35); /* support: IE8 */
background-image: none;
}
.ui-state-disabled .ui-icon {
filter:Alpha(Opacity=35); /* support: IE8 - See #6059 */
}

/* Icons
----------------------------------*/

/* states and images */
.ui-icon {
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
.ui-icon,
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
background-image: url("images/ui-icons_808080_256x240.png");
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
background-image: url("images/ui-icons_847e71_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon,
.ui-state-focus .ui-icon,
.ui-button:hover .ui-icon,
.ui-button:focus .ui-icon {
background-image: url("images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-active .ui-icon,
.ui-button:active .ui-icon {
background-image: url("images/ui-icons_8DC262_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon,
.ui-button .ui-state-highlight.ui-icon {
background-image: url("images/ui-icons_8DC262_256x240.png");
}
.ui-state-error .ui-icon,
.ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {
background-image: url("images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png");
}
.ui-button .ui-icon {
background-image: url("images/ui-icons_eeeeee_256x240.png");
}

/* positioning */
.ui-icon-blank { background-position: 16px 16px; }
.ui-icon-caret-1-n { background-position: 0 0; }
.ui-icon-caret-1-ne { background-position: -16px 0; }
.ui-icon-caret-1-e { background-position: -32px 0; }
.ui-icon-caret-1-se { background-position: -48px 0; }
.ui-icon-caret-1-s { background-position: -65px 0; }
.ui-icon-caret-1-sw { background-position: -80px 0; }
.ui-icon-caret-1-w { background-position: -96px 0; }
.ui-icon-caret-1-nw { background-position: -112px 0; }
.ui-icon-caret-2-n-s { background-position: -128px 0; }
.ui-icon-caret-2-e-w { background-position: -144px 0; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-n { background-position: 0 -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-ne { background-position: -16px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-e { background-position: -32px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-se { background-position: -48px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-s { background-position: -65px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-sw { background-position: -80px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-w { background-position: -96px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-1-nw { background-position: -112px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s { background-position: -128px -16px; }
.ui-icon-triangle-2-e-w { background-position: -144px -16px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-n { background-position: 0 -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-ne { background-position: -16px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-e { background-position: -32px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-se { background-position: -48px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-s { background-position: -65px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-sw { background-position: -80px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-w { background-position: -96px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-1-nw { background-position: -112px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-2-n-s { background-position: -128px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-2-ne-sw { background-position: -144px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-2-e-w { background-position: -160px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-2-se-nw { background-position: -176px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-n { background-position: -192px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-e { background-position: -208px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s { background-position: -224px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrowstop-1-w { background-position: -240px -32px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n { background-position: 1px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-ne { background-position: -16px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e { background-position: -32px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-se { background-position: -48px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s { background-position: -64px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-sw { background-position: -80px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w { background-position: -96px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-nw { background-position: -112px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s { background-position: -128px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-ne-sw { background-position: -144px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-e-w { background-position: -160px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-se-nw { background-position: -176px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-n { background-position: -192px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-e { background-position: -208px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s { background-position: -224px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-w { background-position: -240px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w { background-position: 0 -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-n { background-position: -16px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e { background-position: -32px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-s { background-position: -48px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-w { background-position: -64px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-n { background-position: -80px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e { background-position: -96px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-s { background-position: -112px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w { background-position: -128px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n { background-position: -144px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-e { background-position: -160px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s { background-position: -176px -64px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-4 { background-position: 0 -80px; }
.ui-icon-arrow-4-diag { background-position: -16px -80px; }
.ui-icon-extlink { background-position: -32px -80px; }
.ui-icon-newwin { background-position: -48px -80px; }
.ui-icon-refresh { background-position: -64px -80px; }
.ui-icon-shuffle { background-position: -80px -80px; }
.ui-icon-transfer-e-w { background-position: -96px -80px; }
.ui-icon-transferthick-e-w { background-position: -112px -80px; }
.ui-icon-folder-collapsed { background-position: 0 -96px; }
.ui-icon-folder-open { background-position: -16px -96px; }
.ui-icon-document { background-position: -32px -96px; }
.ui-icon-document-b { background-position: -48px -96px; }
.ui-icon-note { background-position: -64px -96px; }
.ui-icon-mail-closed { background-position: -80px -96px; }
.ui-icon-mail-open { background-position: -96px -96px; }
.ui-icon-suitcase { background-position: -112px -96px; }
.ui-icon-comment { background-position: -128px -96px; }
.ui-icon-person { background-position: -144px -96px; }
.ui-icon-print { background-position: -160px -96px; }
.ui-icon-trash { background-position: -176px -96px; }
.ui-icon-locked { background-position: -192px -96px; }
.ui-icon-unlocked { background-position: -208px -96px; }
.ui-icon-bookmark { background-position: -224px -96px; }
.ui-icon-tag { background-position: -240px -96px; }
.ui-icon-home { background-position: 0 -112px; }
.ui-icon-flag { background-position: -16px -112px; }
.ui-icon-calendar { background-position: -32px -112px; }
.ui-icon-cart { background-position: -48px -112px; }
.ui-icon-pencil { background-position: -64px -112px; }
.ui-icon-clock { background-position: -80px -112px; }
.ui-icon-disk { background-position: -96px -112px; }
.ui-icon-calculator { background-position: -112px -112px; }
.ui-icon-zoomin { background-position: -128px -112px; }
.ui-icon-zoomout { background-position: -144px -112px; }
.ui-icon-search { background-position: -160px -112px; }
.ui-icon-wrench { background-position: -176px -112px; }
.ui-icon-gear { background-position: -192px -112px; }
.ui-icon-heart { background-position: -208px -112px; }
.ui-icon-star { background-position: -224px -112px; }
.ui-icon-link { background-position: -240px -112px; }
.ui-icon-cancel { background-position: 0 -128px; }
.ui-icon-plus { background-position: -16px -128px; }
.ui-icon-plusthick { background-position: -32px -128px; }
.ui-icon-minus { background-position: -48px -128px; }
.ui-icon-minusthick { background-position: -64px -128px; }
.ui-icon-close { background-position: -80px -128px; }
.ui-icon-closethick { background-position: -96px -128px; }
.ui-icon-key { background-position: -112px -128px; }
.ui-icon-lightbulb { background-position: -128px -128px; }
.ui-icon-scissors { background-position: -144px -128px; }
.ui-icon-clipboard { background-position: -160px -128px; }
.ui-icon-copy { background-position: -176px -128px; }
.ui-icon-contact { background-position: -192px -128px; }
.ui-icon-image { background-position: -208px -128px; }
.ui-icon-video { background-position: -224px -128px; }
.ui-icon-script { background-position: -240px -128px; }
.ui-icon-alert { background-position: 0 -144px; }
.ui-icon-info { background-position: -16px -144px; }
.ui-icon-notice { background-position: -32px -144px; }
.ui-icon-help { background-position: -48px -144px; }
.ui-icon-check { background-position: -64px -144px; }
.ui-icon-bullet { background-position: -80px -144px; }
.ui-icon-radio-on { background-position: -96px -144px; }
.ui-icon-radio-off { background-position: -112px -144px; }
.ui-icon-pin-w { background-position: -128px -144px; }
.ui-icon-pin-s { background-position: -144px -144px; }
.ui-icon-play { background-position: 0 -160px; }
.ui-icon-pause { background-position: -16px -160px; }
.ui-icon-seek-next { background-position: -32px -160px; }
.ui-icon-seek-prev { background-position: -48px -160px; }
.ui-icon-seek-end { background-position: -64px -160px; }
.ui-icon-seek-start { background-position: -80px -160px; }
/* ui-icon-seek-first is deprecated, use ui-icon-seek-start instead */
.ui-icon-seek-first { background-position: -80px -160px; }
.ui-icon-stop { background-position: -96px -160px; }
.ui-icon-eject { background-position: -112px -160px; }
.ui-icon-volume-off { background-position: -128px -160px; }
.ui-icon-volume-on { background-position: -144px -160px; }
.ui-icon-power { background-position: 0 -176px; }
.ui-icon-signal-diag { background-position: -16px -176px; }
.ui-icon-signal { background-position: -32px -176px; }
.ui-icon-battery-0 { background-position: -48px -176px; }
.ui-icon-battery-1 { background-position: -64px -176px; }
.ui-icon-battery-2 { background-position: -80px -176px; }
.ui-icon-battery-3 { background-position: -96px -176px; }
.ui-icon-circle-plus { background-position: 0 -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-minus { background-position: -16px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-close { background-position: -32px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e { background-position: -48px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-s { background-position: -64px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w { background-position: -80px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-n { background-position: -96px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-e { background-position: -112px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-s { background-position: -128px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-w { background-position: -144px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-n { background-position: -160px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-zoomin { background-position: -176px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-zoomout { background-position: -192px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-check { background-position: -208px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circlesmall-plus { background-position: 0 -208px; }
.ui-icon-circlesmall-minus { background-position: -16px -208px; }
.ui-icon-circlesmall-close { background-position: -32px -208px; }
.ui-icon-squaresmall-plus { background-position: -48px -208px; }
.ui-icon-squaresmall-minus { background-position: -64px -208px; }
.ui-icon-squaresmall-close { background-position: -80px -208px; }
.ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical { background-position: 0 -224px; }
.ui-icon-grip-dotted-horizontal { background-position: -16px -224px; }
.ui-icon-grip-solid-vertical { background-position: -32px -224px; }
.ui-icon-grip-solid-horizontal { background-position: -48px -224px; }
.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se { background-position: -64px -224px; }
.ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se { background-position: -80px -224px; }


/* Misc visuals
----------------------------------*/

/* Corner radius */
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-top,
.ui-corner-left,
.ui-corner-tl {
border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-top,
.ui-corner-right,
.ui-corner-tr {
border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-bottom,
.ui-corner-left,
.ui-corner-bl {
border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-corner-all,
.ui-corner-bottom,
.ui-corner-right,
.ui-corner-br {
border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

/* Overlays */
.ui-widget-overlay {
background: #2b2922 url("images/ui-bg_inset-soft_15_2b2922_1x100.png") 50% bottom repeat-x;
opacity: .9;
filter: Alpha(Opacity=90); /* support: IE8 */
}
.ui-widget-shadow {
-webkit-box-shadow: -12px -12px 12px #cccccc;
box-shadow: -12px -12px 12px #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<!-- Librerías -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/css/base.css?v=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


<!-- HTML -->
<div>
    <label>Ingrese Fecha:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fecha" readonly id="datepicker">
</div>
```

Comment: como puedo descargar el diseño de css que tiene la pagina oficial?, me sale sin las flechas y no puedo cambiar el mes

Comment: @VictorA. Mira aquí: http://jqueryui.com/download/ Puedes descargar código CSS para cualquier componente de jQuery. He actualizado el código de  la respuesta añadiendo CSS para el datepicker. Verás la diferencia :)

Answer (score 1):

Actualización

El siguiente código lo manejo en la master

```
jQuery(function ($) {
            $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
                closeText: 'Cerrar',
                prevText: '<Ant',
                nextText: 'Sig>',
                currentText: 'Hoy',
                monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
                dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
                weekHeader: 'Sm',
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                firstDay: 1,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: ''
            };
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
        });

        function periodoAnios(tipo) {
            var today = new Date();
            var anioFin = today.getFullYear();
            var anioInicio = anioFin;
            if (tipo == 1) { //Para fechas de nacimiento
                anioInicio -= 100;
            }            
            return anioInicio + ':' + anioFin;
        }

        function creaDatePickers() {
            var periodo = periodoAnios(1);
            $("[id$='txt_midatepicker']").prop('disabled', true);
            $("[id$='txt_midatepicker']").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showAnim: 'drop',
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: 'images/calendario.png',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonText: 'Haga clic para seleccionar la fecha',
                yearRange: periodo
            });

        }

        $(function () {
            creaDatePickers();
        });
```

Luego, en la página donde quiero el datepicker creo un textbox con el mismo ID que define en la master:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_midatepicker" runat="server" CssClass = "texto"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: no me funciona, tampoco puedo determinar el id del input :(

Answer (score 1):

Por un lado, asegúrate de que se carga correctamente la información regional.

En la consola del navegador (F12) escribe simplemente:

```
jQuery.datepicker.regional['es']
```

Esto debería mostrarte un objeto Javascript con la configuración regional. Si no, es posible que no se haya cargado el script.

Si es correcto y sigue sin funcionar puedes intentar establecer el idioma después de crear el datepicker:

```
jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker("option", jQuery.datepicker.regional["es"]);
```

Por otro lado, asegúrate de que estás cargando jQuery y jQueryUI antes del script de localización del datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Incluir los archivos js del datepicker y el de lenguaje (locales)

```
  'resource/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js',
  'resource/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js',


$('.datepicker').datepicker({
'language' : 'es'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se debe llamar al archivo:

```
<script src="js/moments-local-es.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Y configurar el idioma en español de la siguiente forma:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
      locale: moment.locale('es')
    });
  });
```