# DatePicker en español

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Tengo un datepicker y un month funcionan correctamente, el problema es que los dos aparecen en ingles y quiero pasarlos a español, he intentado con varios códigos que he encontrado pero el idioma no cambia a español.

**Código datepicker**

```js
//Librerías
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css"> 
<script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nacimiento" name="nacimiento" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento" required>
</div>

//Script
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            orientation: "auto left",
            forceParse: false,
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            toggleActive: true,
            endDate: '0',
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Código month**

```js
//Librerías
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="dist/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="input-group datepicker">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="text" id="mespago" name="mespago" class="form-control" />
</div>

//Script
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mespago").datepicker({
        format: "MM - yyyy",
        viewMode: "months",
        minViewMode: "months",
    });
</script>
```

**Códigos utilizados cambiándole las variables por las mías**

```js
<script>
    $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '< Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig >',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };

    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
    $(function() {
        $("#fecha").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Mira si [esta solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50875/29967) te sirve. Saludos.

Comment: Pero ¿qué  plugin estás utilizando? Porque en los ejemplos de código que pones unos utilizan el bootstrap-datepicker y otros el de jQuery UI

Comment: @AsierVillanueva amigo por eso en la pregunta coloque que librerías utilizo para el datepicker completo y cuales para el daepicker de solo el mes

Comment: Pero si utilizas los dos tienen que generarte conflictos entre ellos. Además entiendo que la solución no puede ser la misma para los dos casos.

Comment: Con solo pasar todo los días y meses a español como dijo @Willian Rivera en su respuesta me funcionó para los dos datepicker

Comment: y funcionó solo con dos librerías.   <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css"> y <script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Te recomiendo abrir el archivo: `plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js`

Luego busca la palabra "Sunday" por ejemplo y te aparecerá algo como lo siguiente:

```
var q = a.fn.datepicker.dates = {
    en: {
        days: [
            "Sunday",
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday"
        ]
```

Cuando encuentres esto, todos los demás textos en inglés estarán cerca, cambia los días y meses que están en ingles pásalos a español, algo como esto:

```
var q = a.fn.datepicker.dates = {
    en:{
        days: [
            "Domingo",
            "Lunes",
            "Martes",
            "Miércoles",
            "Jueves",
            "Viernes",
            "Sábado"
        ]
```

Y listo tendrás tu datePicker en español.

Comment: Perfecto funcionó

Comment: Excelente, que bueno amigo.

Answer (score 8):

La forma correcta es que descargues el js de tu idioma desde este enlace:
https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/js/locales

Segundo paso es que incluyas el js que descargaste de esta manera:

```
<script src="bootstrap-datepicker.XX.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Y como paso final debes de indicar el idioma en donde inicialisas tu datapicker

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    language: 'es'
});
```

Saludos.

Comment: Si, esta es la forma mas limpia ;)

Answer (score 4):

Prueba asignando la configuración en español en la misma instancia del datepicker

```
<script>

$(function () {
    $("#fecha").datepicker({
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '<Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig>',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: También de esta forma me sirvió

Answer (score 0):

Incluir los archivos js del datepicker y el de lenguaje (locales)

```
  'resource/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js',
  'resource/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js',


$('.datepicker').datepicker({
'language' : 'es'});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, considera revisar [ask], saludos.