# Mostrar solo mes y año en un input de tipo fecha

Tags: html, date, datepicker

Estoy tratando de encontrar una manera de poder eliminar el valor de día en un input de tipo fecha, es decir, lo común es que salga `'09/08/2019'`, no se si hay una manera para que solo sea mes y año (`'08/2019'`).

```html
<form action="" method="POST" class="form-row mb-4">
    <div class="col">
         <label for="fecha">Primera fecha</label>
         <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="form-control" value="2019-08-09">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Podrías usar un `<input type="month">`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Opción 1:** Puedes usar `<input type="month">`:

```html
<form action="" method="POST" class="form-row mb-4">
    <div class="col">
        <label for="fecha">Primera fecha</label>
        <input type="month" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="form-control" value="2019-08">
    </div>
</form>
```

Aunque un problema puede ser que no esta soportado en algunos los navegadores (como Firefox y Explorer).

Para mas información puedes revisar la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month).

**Opción 2:** La opción con datepicker podría ser de la siguiente forma:

**Aclaro que el código no es mio, es de la respuesta de Ben Koehler en Stack Overflow en Ingles [jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2209104/4832311)**

```js
$(function() {
            $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: false,
            dateFormat: 'mm-yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            }
            });
        });
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
    <label for="startDate">Mes :</label>
    <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
</body>
</html>
```

Para cambiar el formato de la fecha puedes cambiar la linea `dateFormat: 'formato',` y colocar el formato que buscas (por ejemplo `'mm-yy'` para `'01-2019'`).

Como esta en ingles puedes intentar cambiarlo a español como indica la respuesta en [DatePicker en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138334/datepicker-en-espa%C3%B1ol)

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Sino en JQuery el datapicker es muy personalizable.

Comment: @Srsole si aunque el problema es que viene en ingles y hay que cambiarle el idioma, luego es una gran opción..

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!

Comment: @VictorAlvarez de nada, que tengas buen día.

Comment: Se que ya esta resuelto, solo para dar informacion, también se puede configurar, es mas puedes decirle que quieres que muestre.

Comment: @Srsole si el OP me lo pide puedo agregar mas información, hasta entonces solo me remito a los limites de la pregunta.

Comment: Era un mero comentario ;)